# WCF Singleton with Session Id

Tags: wcf, session, singleton, sessionid, single-instance

I have a WCF service mapped to 1 hardware device (printer). I want to lock/unlock the printer by client.

Is there a way to make a single instance of that service and also have session enabled? so i can get current user's session id? e.g OperationContext.Current.SessionID ? (save it in a private field so i can sync access to the hardware device)

Thanks!